# "File B with file names" minus/without "file A with file names" aka "what was deleted in A"?

Tags: grep

I want to copy or backup a large folder A to B without `rsync` (just because I can): https://stackoverflow.com/a/65485164/1707015.

It works but from time to time I want to clean up B and delete old files in B (when they are deleted in A).

What I have to get the deleted files in A (so I can then delete them in B also):

```
$ cat A_files.txt  # for example: think the small letters as paths like ./some/path/file.yaml
a
c
d
e
f

$ cat B_files.txt
a
b
c
d

$ \grep -f A_files.txt -F -v B_files.txt
b
```

(The backslash `\` is just for not using any grep aliases with colors or something.)

This works, but only for small files. For files with more than 100 MB file names each, I need > 100 GB RAM :O

Does anyone have a more resource-efficient variant for me? Of course `rsync`, but that is not to be used here just for fun and for practice purposes.

Comment: I am confused: this question is not clear. Mainly with respect to file-names, file-content, lines. I can't work out what is what (without reading code)

Comment: Is it now a bit better?

Comment: Yes I see it now. It has nothing to do with file-names: it could be any text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For list conjunctions / subtraction, the standard command is `comm`. It works on lines of sorted files.

So for the lines of `B_files.txt` that are not in `A_files.txt`:

```
export LC_ALL=C # for a simple and deterministic order and allow any byte
                # in file names.
comm -23 <(sort A_files.txt) <(sort B_files.txt)
```

If the files are already sorted:

```
comm -23 A_files.txt B_files.txt
```

That approach (or yours) doesn't work for arbitrary file names though as file names can contain newline characters, so can't be represented by *lines*.

If you're on a GNU system, you can use NUL delimited records instead of lines and use the `-z` option to `sort` and `comm`.

Another approach is to use zsh's array conjunction/subtraction operators:

```
cd /path/to/A || exit
A_regular_files=(**/*(ND.))
cd /path/to/B || exit
B_regular_files=(**/*(ND.))

files_in_B_but_not_in_A=(${B_regular_files:|A_regular_files})
```

Also note that unless passed the `-x` option, `grep` does substring match. `grep -F foo/bar` matches on `blah/foo/barrage` for instance.

Comment: Thanks: `comm -23 B_files.txt A_files.txt` returns `b`. Woop-di-doo! Notice that I needed to change the order of the arguments. Otherwise it would output `e` and `f`.

Comment: Dude. 41 seconds for all of my files! Without blowing the RAM! CPU load was first high - but who cares! Thanks!

Comment: With `-z`: `xargs: argument line too long` :(

Comment: @uav You need `xargs -0` to work on nul-delimited records.

Comment: Of course, I did. Since I don't expect any line breaks in the paths, it must also work without `-z` or `-0` - and it does.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with:

```
MY_SOURCE=A_files.txt
readarray -t MY_TARGET_ARRAY < B_files.txt
for LINE in "${MY_TARGET_ARRAY[@]}"; do
    if ! grep -q "${LINE}" "${MY_SOURCE}"; then
        echo "${LINE}";
    fi;
done
```

Not tested yet. Propably problems with missing `-x` and/or missing `-F` in `grep`.